# How could I write a code for this problem?

Tags: python, list, optimization

I have given a number of vertices $n$ and a set of edges $E$.

My goal is to write a function that returns a list of $n$ entries, with k-th Place $(k = 0, ..., n-1)$ the $k$-th neighborhood $[k] = {w ∈ V: (k, w) \in E \cup Δ }$ as unordered Node list stands.

My problem is, that i have no idea how to solve this problem.
My written code is 1) not working like it should, second way to slow.

I hope someone of you can help me a little bit. Btw Python is my first language and I'm learning it since 2 weeks, so please do not be too hard :)

```
def get_classes(n,E):
list = []
b = []
a = []
for i in range(n):
    b.append(i)
for i in b:

    for j in E:
        if i ==j[0]:
            a.append(j[1])

    if bool(a) == False:
        list.append(i)

    else:
        list.append(a)
print(list) 
get_classes (4 ,[( 1 , 2 ),(2,1),(1,3)])
```

Comment: Could you give an example without using mathematical notations? Your problem might be very easy but I want to make sure what exactly you want.

Comment: Running your code above gave me this result: [0, [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1], [2, 3, 1]]. Is that the expected result?

Comment: Hey, yes I can:)   So you have 4 vertices V(n) = { 0,1,2,3} and E= [( 1 , 2 ),(2,1),(1,3)] 
The goal is to find all neighbors from this 4 vertices. 
A vertices is called neighbor of v \n V(n)  if there is an edge between it and v.

In this example the result should be list = [ [ ], [2,3],[1],[1] ]

Comment: Two questions: 1) are the edges directed (such that it affects neighbors) and 2) are we assured there are no self-loops?

Comment: @brentertainer Hey, the edges are directed and there are no self loops, it think:()

Comment: @Joshua.M I see. Your code indicated that they are indeed directed. But the example you gave it contradictory. Shouldn't the result instead be `[[], [2, 3], [1], []]`? Node 3 has no edges going away from it, thus it cannot have neighbors, right? I will amend my answer.

Comment: that is  correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should know that `list` is a Python built-in, and you should refrain from assigning objects that name.

Second, your first for loop is unnecessary. You create a list `b` with the elements from `range(n)`, then you loop over those exact same elements again. It would suffice to just have `for i in range(n):` and not create `b` at all.

This solves the problem you pose:

```
def get_classes(n, edges):
    results = []
    for node in range(n):
        result = set()
        for edge in edges:
            if node == edge[0]:
                result.add(edge[1])
        results.append(list(result - {node}))
    return results

results = get_classes(4, [(1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 3)])
print(results)
```

Output:

```
[[], [2, 3], [1], []]
```

Comment: Could you tell me what "|= " does? Never saw this command before

Comment: @Joshua.M I have changed my response to not include that, but I will explain. In Python (and in general), a `set` is a collection of distinct objects, just as it is in the mathematical sense. The `|` symbol is a union for set objects. And `x |= y` means you want to set `x = x | y` or, in prose, that x is assigned the union of x and y.

Answer (score 0):

For that, I would use the Networkx library that is available in python.

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edge(1, 2)
G.add_edge(2, 1)
G.add_edge(1, 3)
G.add_node(0)

result = []
for node in sorted(G.nodes()):     
    result.append(list(G.neighbors(node)))

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[[], [2, 3], [1], [1]]
```

you can install this package using the command:
**pip install networkx**

Check this site : 
https://networkx.github.io/